# Android RoomDatabase exception during inserting data 2nd time

Tags: android, database, exception

I am using RoomDatabase for uploading data to database. I was successful in uploading the data the first time.But the second time when I try to upload another data I got an exception.The problem is at **contactDao.insert(contact);** in the MainActivity.class. It is my first time using Room Database. Please shed some light on this issue.

Exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: contact.index (code 1555)
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
    Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
        (UNIQUE constraint failed: contact.index (code 1555))
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:857)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:50)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
        at com.globemaster.com.roomdatabase.ContactDao_Impl.insert(ContactDao_Impl.java:97)
        at com.globemaster.com.roomdatabase.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Contact.class:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

@Entity(tableName = "contact")
public class Contact {
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @ColumnInfo(name = "index")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int index=1;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "phnmbr")
    @NonNull
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "firstnme")
    private String firstname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastnme")
    String lastname;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(@NonNull String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    }
```

ContactDao(Interface):

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Update;

import java.util.List;
@Dao
public interface ContactDao {
    @Insert
    public void insert(Contact contacts);
    @Update
    public void update(Contact contacts);
    @Delete
    public void delete(Contact contacts);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact")
    public List<Contact> getContacts();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE  `index`=:index" )
    public Contact getContactWithIndex(int index);
}
```

AppDatabase.class:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {Contact.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public  abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ContactDao getContactDAO();
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
appdatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(MainActivity.this,AppDatabase.class,"db-contacts").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
contactDao=appdatabase.getContactDAO();
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Contact contact=new Contact();
         contact.setFirstname(firstname.getText().toString());
         contact.setLastname(lastname.getText().toString());
         contact.setPhoneNumber(phonenumber.getText().toString());
         contactDao.insert(contact);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t use Room, but as I can see, you have a autogenerated primary key, but you always set that to 1, remove the `=1` from the Contact class and your problem should be solved :)

Example:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "index")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int index;
```

Comment: Any idea how to listen for db operations like insert, update in Room?

Comment: Check the LiveData component! It does exactly what you need: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata